# Sessions variables NULL sometimes, othertimes not

Tags: php, session-variables

I have code that creates a session variables for a user on one page. Before the data is entered in the database they go to PayPal to checkout and come back to the site. When they come back those session variables created for the user sometimes remain and sometimes return as NULL.

***User enters their information creates session variables -> Go to PayPal, checkout -> Come back to the site, session variables are sometimes retained going into the database, sometimes not***

I cannot figure out for the life of my why it does it sometimes and not other times. Is there something about sessions that I am missing? Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer you for sure without knowing more information such as part of your code.  how did you notice it is not recording did you log, or did you check if it goes in db? if the latter, then it might be something else such as paypal fail or script.
some other possibilities : session expired, session was started after headers already being sent because of a warning or an error (check error logs), session cookie is associated only with specific subdomain. e.g. user enters site without www. session. but paypal set to return to www. cookie is restricted by subdomain.

Comment: in the later case, check session cookie settings. best way to find out, is to debug by logging a dummy session in a file, and log the url, see when it happens under what circumstances pay attention to tiny details.

Comment: Could it be that session cookies are off? Are only specific browser(s) triggering the error or all of them at random?

Comment: @Dreaded - For now placing session_write_close() fixed it. However, since it is random, I won't really know until more users register. If it happens again I will do some digging into the areas you suggested, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're calling [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) before redirecting to Paypal.

Comment: You, my friend, are the man! That fixed it! I have been battling with this over the past 3 months. Thank you for your help! For anyone else with this same issue, just place session_write_close(); right before directing to PayPal to keep your session variables. Thanks again!